# android ndk dirent.h how to include

Tags: android, android-ndk

I m building a c++ code which requires dirent.h
I found that this file has been include 
SYSROOT = $(NDK)/platforms/android-/arch-arm/

$SYSROOT/usr/include

I want to know how to define SYSROOT so that i can specify it inside Android.mk to include usr/include

Please guide me in this process.
Thanks
Mohit

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to add anything into the Android.mk file to use dirent.h. dirent.h is in a location where the compiler can already find it. Just use `#include <dirent.h>` like you would normally, and it should be fine. If there's a problem, perhaps try updating your ndk to the newest version.